# Creating custom "instruction tips"

Tags: android

I would like to create a view which i could place beside a specific function on the screen as instruction. This "instructiontip" thing will show automatically according to some rules.

The advice I'm seeking is about the way to put such a view anywhere on the screen above all else and not affected by parent type, fx. if added dynamically to a view which root layout is LinearLayout (vertical), I of course don't want it to be places under the last element. I'll place it using coordinates on screen and would expect it to show exactly there.

Here is a design shot for impression:

[image]

I keep thinking that there must be a better way of doing that then just adding it and hoping it will show in place.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/TouchType/CornedBeef)

Comment: @Dipalis. Thanks for your tip. It inspired me to think in the direction of using a `PopupWindow` which I didn't know before.

Answer (score 0):

[Activity.AddContentView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#addContentView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) is a good way of adding such a view above everything else without affecting whatever is beneath. 
The only downside is that you can't remove this view after you added it.. but you can hide it if you need to.